# & operator does not produce char addresses

Tags: c++

I understand what pointer is but for characters and strings it is quite confused to me. I have I piece of code as below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   char greeting[6] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};

   cout << "Address of 'H' is: "; // line 1
   cout << &greeting << endl;     // line 2
   cout << "Address of 'e' is: "; // line 3
   cout << &(greeting[1]) << endl;// line 4
   cout << "Address of 'l' is: "; // line 5 
   cout << &(greeting[2]) << endl;// line 6

   return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

```
Address of 'H' is: 0x7fff30f13600
Address of 'e' is: ello
Address of 'l' is: llo
```

Can someone help me to explain why `line 4` and `line 6` does not produce address?

Comment: Because cout << char*  is specialised ... you want to cast it to a void* if you want the address

Comment: Why do you think `"Address of 'H' is: "` would print the string but `&(greeting[1])` wouldn't? Think about what types these are.

Comment: try `cout << &greeting << &greeting[0]` and see. And [don't use `endl` unless you really want its behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/995714), use `'\n'` instead

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with the address-of operator `&` in this case.

The operator

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*);
```

is a specialized overload to output NUL terminated C-strings.

If you want to print the address, use a cast to `void*`:

```
cout << (void*)&greeting[1] << endl;
```

Comment: Or cast to `uintptr_t`.

Comment: Can you explain the reason for that?

Comment: @user2671755 The reason is that C++ assumes `char*` refers to a string you want to print. It's a special case for that pointer type alone.

Comment: @user2671755 As mentioned the purpose of the specialization is to output  NUL terminated C-strings.

Comment: @Lundin: C++ does not assume that. It's the function that determines how to interpret it. A different C++ function could interpret it differently.

Answer (score 0):

Because strings are actually a charachter arrays.

when printing cout << greetings

it is the equivalent of cout << &(greetings[0])

which is starting printing chars from the address of the first char until you hit a null terminator.